# SharpDevelop: cant change my app display name

Tags: c#, sharpdevelop

I'm using SharpDevelop to create a C# application. SD has named my application after the project name and I have no idea were to change it manually now. I searched everywhere and still no luck. Will be grateful for your advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your project there should be a file called AssemblyInfo.cs. Open it and try to learn what are the attributes defined in it.

Comment: Yeah, I found it after some time but I thought it was also somewhere in the options. Thanks for the info anyway - you reassured me that it is what it is.

Comment: It is also available in options, but could not be easily figured out. Anyway any changes are finally saved in AssemblyInfo.cs, so editing it directly won't hurt.